# Drawing bigger text using glutBitmapCharacters

Tags: opengl, text, drawing, glut

I managed to draw text in opengl using glutBitmapCharacters. Now i wanna draw a title but it has to have a bigger size. How do i do that?
Here is the code for my drawtext function:

```
   void drawText(const char *text,int length , int x , int y)
 {
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   double *matrix = new double[16];
   glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,matrix);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(0,800,0,600,-5,5);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glPushMatrix();
   glLoadIdentity();
   glRasterPos2i(x,y);
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
       glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15,(int)text[i]);
   delete matrix;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`glutBitmapCharacter` uses `glBitmap` under the hood. So you *cannot* change the text size; it will be the exact pixel size of the text.

If you want text who's size can be changed, you need to use the "Stroke" character functions (such as `glutStrokeCharacter`). These draw actual triangles and such, who's size can be adjusted via matrix scale operations (`glScale`).

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @NicolBolas answer, you can *always* scale raw bitmap data (just like imaging programs, e.g. Photoshop, can), though the results, especially regarding fonts, might not always be satisfactory. Scaling by a natural number will always be pixel-perfect, though.

To use such scaling, you will need to render your fonts to texture. You can then render them as textured quads to screen, and use built-in OpenGL scaling.

Please note that I'm **not** recommending this approach. If you need more sophisticated features, perhaps a bigger and more featured library, like `freetype-gl`, would be appropriate.